# What is the idea behind creating levels for iPhone games?

Tags: iphone

I want to know how different levels are made in iPhone games like "AngryBirds". Do they have some large array which has locations where to put the brick or something? How do those kinds of levels are developed?

Answer (score 2):

You store the level data like any other information, typically in a file. Depending on your needs, it might be best if this file is a plist, an sqlite database, or some custom format. Then, when a level is loaded, the program reads the appropriate file and creates data structures, such as objects, dictionaries, and arrays, to store the data it needs in the way it needs it.

Comment: I quod also recommend exploring the cocos2d library.  There are some wonderful tutorials available and it has been used to develop some very high profile apps.